# NULL Pointer Call Fail Immediately

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a NULL pointer named pTest. Is it possible to make the application crash immediately, if a function is invoked using the pointer.

Comment: `pTest` is a null pointer to what?  Is it a function pointer or something you're passing as an argument?  If the latter, you can do something like `if (pTest == NULL) abort()` in the function.

Comment: @KeithThompson And if it's the former, it should blow up on its own.

Comment: @jpm: It *should*, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: You can add an "assert(this);" to the functions. It's not technically legal, but it works on your platform.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Why is it not `technically` legal?

Comment: Because there is no legal way `this` can ever be NULL, so the compiler is free to assume it's not and ignore your `assert` entirely. But in practice, it works.

Comment: Not to mention that `assert` is meant for debugging, and can be disabled by a compiler flag. Not a very robust approach to error handling.

Comment: @jpm: Yeah, good point. I guess it depends on exactly why the OP wants the program to crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a raw pointer, you can create a protected pointer class (a form of smart pointer) that traps dereferences.

```
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
class CheckedPointer
{
    T * ptr;
public:
    CheckedPointer(T * init = NULL) : ptr(init) {}
    T * operator->() const
    {
        if (ptr == NULL)
            throw std::runtime_error("dereference of NULL pointer");
        return ptr;
    }
    T & operator*() const
    {
        if (ptr == NULL)
            throw std::runtime_error("dereference of NULL pointer");
        return *ptr;
    }
    // ... more members to make this a useful class
};

class Test
{
public:
    void Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    CheckedPointer<Test> pTest;
    pTest->Foo();
}
```

http://ideone.com/R4mUK

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs clarification. If pTest is a null pointer to an object and you invoke a method on it, then I'd expect your VS2008 compiled program to crash on its own if either:

1. The method is virtual
2. The method tries to access an instance member

This implies that the method call may actually work if it's semantically static and doesn't try to access instance members. Furthermore, the behaviour of this sort of thing varies between debug and release builds.

But if *you* are wanting to make your app crash directly before/when a method invocation is attempted, then you can add assertions or conditional aborts before each one. Or you could add a (this == NULL) check at the beginning of each method (but this won't work on virtual methods which will trigger a crash before reaching this point).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to throw an Exception and just never catch it. That will crash your program.

```
if (pTest == NULL)
  throw std::invalid_argument("null pointer");
```